# natbib - Citation in separate tex files

Tags: citing, natbib

Im having troubles with citations in my PhD thesis. I already looked into other posts, but I could not find any solution.... I would be very happy if someone could help me.

I want one bibliography at the end of my thesis, consisting of several chapters in separate files.

**EDIT:**

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test1.tex}
\chapter{Chapter One}
Text1 \cite{nishikawa_unique_2006} 
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{test2.tex}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
Text2 \cite{struchholz_functional_2009}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{test3.tex}
\chapter{Chapter Three}
Text3 \cite{nishikawa_unique_2006} \cite{struchholz_functional_2009}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper, liststotoc, bibtotoc, 12pt, numbers=noenddot, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[authoryear,comma,nonamebreak,round,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\include{test1}
\include{test2}
\include{test3}
\bibliography{literature}
\end{document}
```

The .bib file contains

```
@article{nishikawa_unique_2006,
    title = {A unique mechanism for the processive movement of single-headed myosin-{IX}},
    volume = {343},
    abstract = {XXX},
    language = {en},
    number = {4},
    urldate = {2020-03-23},
    journal = {Biochemical and Biophysical Research Communications},
    author = {Nishikawa, Masatoshi and Nishikawa, So and Inoue, Akira and Iwane, Atsuko Hikikoshi and Yanagida, Toshio and Ikebe, Mitsuo},
    month = may,
    year = {2006},
    pages = {1159--1164},
}

@article{struchholz_functional_2009,
    title = {Functional {Role} of the {Extended} {Loop} 2 in the {Myosin} 9b {Head} for {Binding} {F}-actin},
    volume = {284},
    language = {en},
    number = {6},
    urldate = {2020-03-23},
    journal = {Journal of Biological Chemistry},
    author = {Struchholz, Sandra and Elfrink, Kerstin and Pieper, Uwe and Kalhammer, Georg and Honnert, Ulrike and Grützner, Anika and Linke, Wolfgang A. and Liao, Wanqin and Bähler, Martin},
    month = feb,
    year = {2009},
    pages = {3663--3671},
}
```

This example works, but If include my written chapter (80 pages) than it does not work and I get just ?? instead of the citations.... Somehow there is a problem with my external files, but it just contains text and citations

Comment: Please provide a full example that does not work on your system. We do not have access to the files  you input here. (we probably does not need all the inputtet files). I made a simple example with just one citation in `Introduction.tex`, no problems at all. Remember that it goes: latex, bibtex, latex, latex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Im quite new to LaTeX, so I just had to figure out how to make a minimal working example.

Comment: I edited my question abov... I got already one step further, but it still not ok

Comment: Then you'll have to dig deeper into debugging. Are you sure you don't get any errors or warnings in your compilation? BTW: if you use @name to the person you're replying to they get notified by the site.

Comment: @daleif: I found the problem now and fixed it. :-) The citations in my document where not hyperlinked and did not turned green. When I clicked on them, they changed colour and It worked

Comment: Erh that does not make much sense. Additionally using hyperref and not including it in the example is quite bad. Hyperref changes a lot of things and thus its presence is very important.